# Реализация задачи на Java

Tags: java

Обход дерева на заданную глубину без использования рекурсии.

Написать консольное приложение на Java, которое принимает три параметра:
- путь к начальной директории (rootPath)
- глубина поиска - неотрицательное целое число (depth)
- маска - строка (mask)

Приложение должно найти все элементы дерева файловой системы находящиеся на
глубине depth от корня дерева rootPath, которые в своем имени содержат строку mask.
Требования:
- Приложение должно быть реализовано БЕЗ использования рекурсии.
- Приложение не должно зависеть от ОС.

---

Необходима помощь в решении этого алгоритма, особенно в реализации поиска нужных файлов на заданную глубину.

Comment: а в чём проблема возникла? Думаю вам стоит разбить вопрос на части, например "как получить список файлов в папке" "как обойти дерево в глубину без рекурсии" и так далее. В целом задача не сложная поэтому не ясно в чём проблема. На данном ресурсе не принято делать задания _за кого-то_, тут помогают в решении.

Comment: Я понимаю как получить файлы и список каталог текущей директории, но как получить все файлы подкаталогов?

Comment: public class Catalog {

  
    public Catalog(String rootPacht, int deth, String mask) {
        this.rootPacht = rootPacht;
        this.deth = deth;
        this.mask = mask;
    }
 
    public void readCatalog() throws IOException {

        // определяем объект для каталога
        File dir = new File(rootPacht);

        // Список всех объектов каталога
        File[] nameFile = dir.listFiles();

        for (File nameFile1 : nameFile) {
            
            if(nameFile1.isDirectory()){
            
          
            
            }

Comment: Потом возникает вопрос, как реализовать получение не всех элементов директории, а только например до 3 уровня вложенности дерева файловой системы?

Comment: Возможно просто дадите список литературы, куда необходимо копать для реализации этой задачи,если она вам кажется не сложной?

Comment: внесите что есть в вопрос, чуть чётче мысль сформулируйте, да прямо тут и ответим. Я так понимаю проблема именно обойти дерево на какую-то глубину. Это решается с помощью любого динамического массива и реализацией поиска в ширину или глубину (что удобнее).

Comment: Более четкий вопрос: что значит не зависимость от ОС при прохождении файловой системы в java?

Comment: @kolibrikiev Независимость от ос - это как раз вообще не вопрос применительно к java. Стоковые функции не зависят от ос, Наоборот, надо постараться, чтобы найти библиотеки классов, зависимые от ос.

Comment: Спасибо за комментрии, я создал алгоритм действий под задачу, поправте ,если где то ошибся в логике.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, я создал алгоритм действий под задачу, поправьте ,если где то ошибся в логике. 1. Создаем массив для того, чтобы хранить там полученные файлы из директории. 2.Вносим в него первоначальную  стартовую директорию. 3. Создаем цикл в котором определяем уровень вложенности и проходим по массиву, перебирая элементы проверяем есть ли среди них каталоги.4. Если встречаем каталог , выбираем его элементы, заносим его в этот же массив, чтобы при следующих итерациях вытащить с них все элементы.5. После перебора элементов и проверки их на условия в задаче удаляем.

Comment: Будет ли являться количество итераций цикла  уровнем вложенность каталога?

Comment: Алгоритм правильный , решение задачи найдено.

Comment: @kolibrikiev если у вас есть решение, предлагаю его опубликовать как ответ. Обязательно кому-нибудь ещё пригодится.